# Count how many HashMap entries have a given value

Tags: java, hashmap, key

```
public final static HashMap<String, Integer> party = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
party.put("Jan",1);
party.put("John",1);
party.put("Brian",1);
party.put("Dave",1);
party.put("David",2);
```

How can I return a number of **how many people** has the value **1**

Comment: Iterate the *values* collection and compare each value with `1`.

Comment: Its java, Iterate could be done. Maybe there was an other way.

Comment: @user1621988 Please could you accept this answer if you're happy with it

Answer (score 28):

I'd just use the Collections.frequency() method on the HashMap values, like this.

```
int count = Collections.frequency(party.values(), 1);
System.out.println(count);
===> 4
```

Or the general solution, generate a map of frequency against number.

```
Map<Integer, Integer> counts = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
for (Integer c : party.values()) {
    int value = counts.get(c) == null ? 0 : counts.get(c);
    counts.put(c, value + 1);
}
System.out.println(counts);
==> {1=4, 2=1}
```

Answer (score 10):

Using Java 8:

```
party.values().stream().filter(v -> v == 1).count();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
int counter = 0;
Iterator it = party.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
  Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
  if(pairs.getValue() == 1){
    counter++; 
  }      
}
System.out.println("number of 1's: "+counter);
```

Comment: Why do you modify `party` using `Iterator.remove`? That information might be needed later.

Comment: How exactly do you *avoid* `ConcurrentModificationException` by *modifying* the structure?

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about :P

Comment: Now seriously, it was in the original code example and I didn't think about moving it. Since HashMap iterator has the "fail-fast" property, it might throw an exception if the structure under it changes.Still, I agree with you that we shouldn't modify the awesome `party` here. Code modified.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this

```
HashMap<String, Integer> party = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
party.put("Jan",1);
party.put("John",1);
party.put("Brian",1);
party.put("Dave",1);
party.put("David",2);

Set<Entry<String, Integer>> set = party.entrySet();
for (Entry<String, Integer> me : set) {
    if(me.getValue()==1)
    System.out.println(me.getKey() + " : " + me.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try out this library for a lot of such group by function
http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/wiki/LambdajFeatures

```
HashMap<String, Integer> party = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    party.put("Jan",1);
    party.put("John",1);
    party.put("Brian",1);
    party.put("Dave",1);
    party.put("David",2);
    List<Integer> list = filter(equalTo(1),party.values());
    System.out.println(list.size());
```

You might need to import these maven dependencies

> ```
> <dependency>
>       <groupId>com.googlecode.lambdaj</groupId>
>      <artifactId>lambdaj</artifactId>
>     <version>2.3.3</version>
> ```

and hamcrest matchers for

```
equalTo(1)
```